# substitution "None" to the object that returns the NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, biopython

I have many `xml` files for parsing the data I am using python.

For example, please regard the `Object` as the result of parsed `xml` data.
Morever, the `Object` have `Object_A` that I want to parse.

My problem is that there are cases that `Object` is existing, but `Object_A` is not existing.
In this case, `Object_A` returns the `NameError` and I couldn't continue the process.

If `Object` have no `Object_A` data, I want to substitute `NA` value(strings) like below codes.

My Question is that Can I substitute `None` to the `Object_A` like my codes.

Please tell me how to solve this case.

```
for Object in Objects:
    for Object_A in Objects_A:         
        try:
            Object_A

        except NameError:
            Object_A is None


        if Object_A is not None:
           # some treatment to parse the data(I omitted the code)

        else:
           # instead of parsing the data, subsituting strings "NA"(I omitted the code)
```

[Edited]

Below is whole codes.
Above code is modified version of my codes for easy understanding.
So, Above codes and below code is not same.

Here I'm using BioPython modules.
And, Objects_A is species_record.descriptions and Object_A is description.
Sorry for the confusion.

```
## process of rearrange of blast search result ##
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio import SearchIO
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML

## path seting
path = 'C:/Users/......................'
os.chdir(path)

# reading the DNA alignment
# getting the untreated folders（"_bf" means treated files）
folder_names = [folder_name for folder_name in glob.glob(path + '/' + '*') if "_bf_ald" not in folder_name]

DNA_SampleID = []
Title = []
Score = []
E_value = []
Order_Index = []

# getting the untreated files
for folder_name in folder_names:
    xml_names = [xml_name for xml_name in glob.glob(folder_name + '/*.xml')]
    csv_name = folder_name.strip(path).split("\\")[1]

    for xml_name in xml_names:

        # get the sample ID
        dna_sampleid = xml_name.strip(folder_name).split(".")[0]

        # opening the xml files
        seq_blast_result = open(xml_name)
        species_records = NCBIXML.parse(seq_blast_result)


        dna_sampleID = []
        e_value = []
        score = []
        title = []
        order_index  = []

        for species_record in species_records:
            for description in species_record.descriptions:

                try:
                    description

                except NameError:
                    description is None

                if description is not None:
                    title.append(description.title)
                    score.append(description.score)
                    e_value.append(description.e)
                    dna_sampleID = [dna_sampleid]*len(title)
                    order_index = [num for num in range(1, len(title) + 1)]

                else:
                    title.append('NA')
                    score.append('NA')
                    e_value.append('NA')
                    dna_sampleID = [dna_sampleid]*1
                    order_index.append('NA')


            DNA_SampleID.extend(dna_sampleID)
            Title.extend(title)
            Score.extend(score)
            E_value.extend(e_value)
            Order_Index.extend(order_index)
```

Comment: Can you give the whole code. That would help in conducting the problem you are facing.

Comment: I showed my codes. If it is no trouble, please check my codes.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear, but from what I understand

you used `Object_A is None` which comparation rather than an assignment

`Object_A is None` is a conditional expression (that returns `True` if `Object_A` is `None`, otherwise `False`)

To change the value of Object_A, use 
`Object_A = None`